# Multiple Definition Error Linking Static Library

Tags: c++, linker, g++

EDIT this is solved:
The issue was even though I was rebuilding the library after edits to my sources files I wasn't deleting the library before trying my tests again and it had some old files in there.

So I have a library which is set up like so

individual.h

```
#ifndef INDIVIDUAL_H
#define INDIVIDUAL_H
....
namespace dgal {
    class individual {
        public:
            individual() = delete;
            individual(const size_t numWeights);
            individual(const std::shared_ptr<dgal::individual> parentA, const std::shared_ptr<dgal::individual> parentB);
            ...
    };

}
#endif
```

individual.cpp

```
#include "individual.h"
...
dgal::individual::individual(const size_t numWeights) : weights(numWeights) {
    ...
}

dgal::individual::individual(const std::shared_ptr<dgal::individual> parentA, const std::shared_ptr<dgal::individual> parentB){
    ...
}
```

which is compiled and put into a static library

My makefile to build my tests is like so

```
includes = -I../src/
LDLIBS = -L../build -ldgal -pthread
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra $(includes)

all:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test.out main.cpp $(LDLIBS)
    @echo "Tests built"
```

and main.cpp looks like:

```
...
class test : public dgal::individual {
    public:
        test() : dgal::individual(10) {std::cout << "test constructor" << std::endl;}
        test(const std::shared_ptr<dgal::individual> a, const std::shared_ptr<dgal::individual> b) : dgal::individual(a, b) {}
};

int main(){

    std::shared_ptr<test> A(new test);
    std::shared_ptr<test> B(new test);

    std::shared_ptr<test> C(new test(A,B));
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting a multiple definition error from g++ about my `dgal::individual::individual(unsigned long)` which is really my `size_t` constructor. However it doesn't come up with an error until I try to use my `test(const std::shared_ptr<dgal::individual> a, const std::shared_ptr<dgal::individual> b)` constructor, I don't understand where the multiple definitions are coming from.

Edit exact error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -I../src/ -o test.out main.cpp -L../build -ldgal -pthread
../build/libdgal.a(individual.o): In function `dgal::individual::individual(unsigned long)':
individual.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `dgal::individual::individual(unsigned long)'
../build/libdgal.a(individual.o):individual.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
../build/libdgal.a(individual.o): In function `dgal::individual::individual(unsigned long)':
individual.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `dgal::individual::individual(unsigned long)'
../build/libdgal.a(individual.o):individual.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

and if I edit the default constructor to not be deleted and try to use the default constructor instead of the one with arguments then it works fine and does not complain about multiple definitions

Comment: Suggest show us the actual error, and how bout the whole individual class header?

Comment: What you've shown compiles fine with both gcc 4.8.1 and clang 3.2.1. What exact error are you getting?

Comment: Also provide us the list of files included in each file.

Comment: Better still, prepare a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org). (I should hotkey this.)

Comment: Please post the linker errors, not some vague description of them.

Comment: Editted with exact error output. @kris123456 that is the list of files the rest is just standard library stuff.